# Detect L-shapes in point cloud

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a laserscanner which send me the distance to something as a [x,y]

As you can see on the picture, I want to detect the L-shapes in the pointcloud to know where the parking space is.

[image]

How can I Mark the L-shape?

Maybe it´s helpful to know that I use Matlab R2015 with a Simulink model.

Comment: Can you provide more details? It's difficult to understand your question.

Comment: OK, sorry. I have a laserscanner which send me the distance to something as a [x,y]. As you can see on the picture, I want to detect the L-shapes in the pointcloud to know where the parking space is. How can I Mark the L-shape? http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/32008/ParkingSpace.jpg

Comment: You could use [`hough`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/hough.html) to detect lines, and then check for pairs of lines that form right angles.  You'll have to first convert your data to an image, but this shouldn't be too complicated.  If there is a point inside a pixel, set it to 1.  Otherwise, set the pixel to 0.